# C# Metro HttpClient not receiving cookie on PostAsync

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to log in to a website using .NET 4.5 HttpClient and receive a cookie. I break right before leaving the try and check the CookieContainer and it contains no cookies. The response sends back a 200 status though.

```
private async void Login(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        Uri address = new Uri(@"http://website.com/login.php");
        CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            CookieContainer = cookieJar
        };
        handler.UseCookies = true;
        handler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler as HttpMessageHandler)
        {
            BaseAddress = address
        };

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(string.Format("username={0}&password={1}&login=Login&keeplogged=1", username, password));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content);
    }
```

I have no clue why this isn't working. It works fine when I try .NET 4 style.

Comment: btw: use [FormUrlEncodedContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent(v=vs.110)) instead of StringContent with string.Format. Your code doesn't properly escape the user name and password.

Comment: @dtb that is the answer, if you want to post it as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [FormUrlEncodedContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent%28v=vs.110%29) instead of [StringContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent%28v=vs.110%29) with [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx). Your code doesn't properly escape the user name and password.

```
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login", "Login"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("keeplogged", "1")
});
```

Comment: how can I pass this cookie to a webview? so that I can display a webpage using that cookie?

Comment: also this sends the information as post and not as headers or cookie. How can I send it as header/cookie?

Comment: @MilanAggarwal: Sounds like a good question to [ask at StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: already did but no response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418383/set-cookies-for-webview-via-code-for-win-store-app)