# set cookies/headers for webview via code for Win Store App

Tags: cookies, webview, header, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to set cookies for my `webview` via the code. I know it was not possible in windows phone. But is it now possible in windows 8? Can anyone guide me?

Alternate Option: Can I pass Headers while navigating to a URL in windows 8?

In windows phone

```
     Navigate(URL, [Flags,] [TargetFrameName,] [PostData,] [Headers])
```

In Windows 8

```
     Navigate(Uri source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but the WebView control won't do that for you.

You can acomplish what you want creating a custom WebRequest with the desired headers, and then call WebView.NavigateToString() with the content of the WebResponse.

Comment: I have done this too but in that case the parameters I set go as post parameter and not as header or cookies. Could you help me with some code? Also the content I receive contains JS functions which throw error. Is it because the JS is not present when I do NavigateToString?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 you can do:

```
// using Windows.Web.Http;
// using Windows.Web.Http.Filters;

Uri uri = new Uri("http://kiewic.com/your/url/");

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("fooName", uri.Host, "/");
cookie.Value = "barValue";

HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
HttpCookieManager cookieManager = filter.CookieManager;
cookieManager.SetCookie(cookie, false);

MyWebView.Navigate(uri);
```