# Winrt WebView Http headers

Tags: c#, webview, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I need pass cookies in http headers in WebView(metro application/windows store application/winrt application). I know, it is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418383/set-cookies-headers-for-webview-via-code-for-win-store-app?lq=1). The problem is, when I get response of webrequest with headers and navigate WebView to response's content as string I do not get styles(css), scripts(js) working. Accessing single facebook page tells me, I have old browser. Is there anyway to achieve WebView.Navigate(Uri) behavior but with http headers?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the security concept of windows store apps.

My best guess is that you're trying to implement OAuth to support login through facebook. If I am right you could try the [client side login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-without-js-sdk/). This one sends the access token as the fragment of the redirect Uri. Since the fragment is part of the Uri you can read it using the [`WebView.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.source) property.

For more information about the WebView please see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx) on msdn.

Comment: I need not only OAuth2 for facebook, but a lot more interactions with different servers through headers. Your answer definitely works with FB, but I would like to find more general solution. Thank you for answer!